# Non Scrollable HTML content with table headers

Tags: html, css

I wanted a html page which has a html header and a table header to have non scrollable feature. Only the table contents should be scrollable.

For ex:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>header</h1>
        <h1>header2</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>address</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Venkat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>bangalore</td>
                </tr>
                //this part will be repeating
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want only the contents in the table body to be scrollable.

I had referred the following link also [How do you create non scrolling div at the top of an HTML page without two sets of scroll bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256811/how-do-you-create-non-scrolling-div-at-the-top-of-an-html-page-without-two-sets)

But i cannot use the div to only contain headers and table header..

I have created a fiddle with a situation similar to mine. Please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/VenkateshManohar/bU7NN/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Scrollable Table with fixed headers using CSS!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584702/how-to-add-a-scrollbar-to-an-html5-table)

Answer (score 0):

You will can find a jQuery plugin [here](http://fixedheadertable.com/) that will do it for you ;)

Comment: Tried this plugin. Even that is not working for me.. I did not get any error.. But the table was as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this: **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/H2Ayq/)**

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="dataGridHeader">
  <div class="dataGridContent">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="scrolltablestyle style-even">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="160">Shopper Name</th>
          <th width="160">First Name</th>
          <th width="160">Last Name</th>
          <th width="160">User ID</th>
          <th width="160">Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
          <td width="160">John</td>
          <td width="160">Doe</td>
          <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
          <td width="160">Enabled</td>
        </tr>

.
.
.
.
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried this... The functionality is working fine.But in my table i have columns which are hidden and can be displayed dynamically using multiselect bootstrap. Hence the width of the table header columns and rows are not matching...Do you have any suggestions for that.

Comment: Even using this fiddle solution is not working in my case. As there are some columns which are hidden by multiselect and those can be made visible dynamically.apart from that when i use this solution the header and column will not have same width.. Thanks for your time and suggestion..

Comment: I have created a fiddle for the same please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/VenkateshManohar/bU7NN/